# Add assert statements to both of these functions enforcing the preconditions

Tags: assertion

Both before_space and after_space have the same preconditions. Add assert statements to both of these functions enforcing the preconditions.

def before_space(s):
"""
Returns the substring of s up to, but not including, the first space.

```
Example: before_space('Hello World') returns 'Hello'

Parameter s: the string to slice
Precondition: s is a string with at least one space in it
"""

return s[0] * (s[0] != ' ') + (before_space(s[1:]) if s[0] != ' ' else '')
```

def after_space(s):
"""
Returns the substring of s after the first space

```
Example: after_space('Hello World') returns 'World'

Parameter s: the string to slice
Precondition: s is a string with at least one space in it
"""

return (s[1:] * (s[0] == ' ')) + (after_space(s[1:]) * (s[0] != ' ')) if len(s) > 0 else ''
```

I have tried:

assert ' ' in s, "Input must contain a space character"

or

if not isinstance(s, str):
raise AssertionError("Input must be a string")
assert ' ' in s, "Input must contain a space character"

and i either get errors back The call before_space(1) did not enforce the function precondition.

or
The call after_space('Hello World') no longer works properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError: Input must contain a space character.